# How can I check if 24 hours have passed between two dates in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, date, datetime, sharedpreferences, date-difference

I need to check if 24 hours have passed between two dates. If 24 hours have passed, I will update the data in my room database, if not, I will not. How can I do that. I thought about keeping a date with shared preferences and comparing that date with the current date, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that the different between the date stored in shared pref as an `Long` and the current date are bigger than or equal the value of 1 day in millis

```kotlin
var isDayPassed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - date) >= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)
```

Note: Make sure to import `TimeUnit` using `import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`

Comment: IsDayPassed returns true or false if 24 hours have passed, right? if i didn't misunderstand. This way I can check

Comment: Yes right and you can use it to check